# Doorkeeper and OAuth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I always have this error when I follow ryan's tutorial to how to use [Doorkeeper to protect rest API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper):

> OAuth2::Error: invalid_grant: The provided authorization grant is
>   invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in
>   the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The provided
>   authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the
>   redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
>   another client."}

when I'm in the phase of parsing token. What is the problem and how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an habit of adjusting my time 20 minutes ahead and it's the source of this problem. Change back the time by synchronizing, now everything works :)

Comment: What do you mean the time? System time?